# How do I make Thunderbird open HTTPS links in firefox for Thunderbird Add-ons?

Tags: firefox, email, thunderbird

I have been trying to figure this out all night. When I try to set a theme in thunderbird it asks for me to select an application to open HTTPS links. I cannot find firefox in any of the folders I check so I can't select anything. I have used:

```
    whereis firefox
```

These are all the folders I have checked when using the Thunderbird select app.

```
    firefox: /usr/bin/firefox /usr/lib/firefox /etc/firefox /usr/share/man/man1/firefox.1.gz
```

but still no luck on locating it.

[Thunderbird application request.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxZLh.png)

Answer (score 0):

The protocol is not dependent on the browser, but the hosting provider of the website you are opening. If the website has an SSL Certificate installed, it will go through the HTTPS protcol/:443 port and the force SSL connections are server rules that are added to the serve's vhosts files. You can't alter those settings via the browser.

Are you trying ti disable the option to open websites at all that doesn't have HTTPS connections?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have added more detail. I'm trying to install a background add-on but when I click on the background it tries to open the link to my web browser. It asks me to select an application to open the HTTPS link, but I cannot select firefox or find it anywhere.

Comment: Which app are you trying to install? Are you sure it is an official application? It sounds like that is a malware injector or a browser hijacker prompt to me judging from your description.